# Is there a way to manage BOM dependancies in python to uniformize multiproject dependancies

Tags: python, dependency-management

I'm coming from the java world and both [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) and [graddle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) have a [great BOM feature](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2019/04/gradle-goodness-use-bill-of-materials.html) where we can define a list of dependancies with the version rules independantly from any project. Then in a project we can say I need those dependancies and use the version defined in the BOM file.

This help a lot at keeping multi project dependancies in sync when they are devloped in parallel. It also avoid having broken build because a dependancy was upgraded in a project but not in another dependant project.

How can we properly manage dependencies across many projects in python like the BOM feature of java allow?

I'm now migrating a few python/django project to poetry (leaving basic pip/requirement.txt), but open to other solution tool as we are still early in that migration (only did initial test as poc)

Comment: By the way, I've been searching on internet for such a tool and only thing found is to generate a "bom" mostly for compliance and dependencies analysis, not actually for build the app

Comment: Maybe rez? https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/rez

Comment: that seam to be a package manager more than build dependency management. I'll look a bit more in the doc, but not sure it really address properly the issue

Comment: You may be interested in how the [the OpenStack project tackled this exact problem](https://docs.openstack.org/project-team-guide/dependency-management.html).

Comment: Interesting idea, way more complex than a standalone tool, but we could take idea from that at our own level.